# Unable to click on checkbox in Selenium

Tags: checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I have tried xPath, CssSelector, tagName, Name, id but it always throw an error that "element not visible"

HTML is

```
<div class="alertType nonEv" style="display: block;">
<span style="font-family:designk-bold; font-size:x-large; color:#444">MAINTENANCE & DIAGNOSTICS ALERTS</span>
<br>
<ul>
<li>
<span>500 miles before maintenance</span>
<input id="" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Y" name="">
<label class="noShow"></label>
<input id="" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Y" name="">
<label class="noShow"></label>
<input id="maint100" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Y" name="maint100">
<label class="col3" for="maint100"></label>
</li>
```

Please help

Comment: Please be more precise , which check-box or web-element you want to check?

Comment: Here in example i have to check on the webelement which has id 'maint100'. It is done by javascript but i am looking for other than javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you get an ElementNotVisibleException that indicates that you have actually located the element you want to interact with. In short, an ElementNotVisibleException means that the element you are trying to interact with is either hidden or overlayed by another element.

If the problem was that you could not locate the desired element, you should be getting an NoSuchElementException. A such exception indicates that there are no elements that match the conditions used when trying to locate the element(s).